# R - Threshold linear regression model

Tags: r, linear-regression, threshold, markov-chains, autoregressive-models

I am looking for a package in R containing a threshold regression model or a threshold autoregressive (ar) model with extra exogenous explonatary variables for time series?  By now I came across following packages, which do not fully capture the behaviour I am looking for:

- pdR (seems like right choice, however ptm function is for panel data
  not a time series data and doesn't work when I set a number of
  cross-section units to 1)
- chngpt (simillar to above, furthemore not a treshold specification I am looking for)
- tsDyn (I want ex-post treshold not a transition matrix)
- TAR (cannot add exogenous variables)
- threg (can't say exacly what it does, but not what I am lookign for)

Your help will be very welcomed!